Conditional Statement in Makefile is mistaken
I am trying to write a Makefile to help compiling my resume in two languages, German as well as in English.
I come to know conditional statement and tried using this following way:
# Variables Declaration                                                                                                                 
LANG               = DE
rule:
ifeq ($(LANG), DE)
        FILE               = ./directory/resume_de
else ifeq ($(LANG), EN)
        FILE               = ./directory/resume_en
else
        echo "LANG is not set, use DE/EN"; exit 1
endif

all: ${FILE}.pdf move

${FILE}.pdf: ${FILE}.tex
        latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=${PDFLATEX} -f -use-make ${FILE}.tex  


So basic idea at my end was that if LAN is DE/EN, the corresponding resume would be generated. However, it looks like that I misunderstand the concept of conditional operator in Makefile.
Could someone please comment how could I serve my purpose of using single command line to be able to work on both language resume in Makefile.

More fundamentally, I would expect the Makefile to always produce both versions if I simply run make. You might put in secondary phonies so that you could (say) make Englisch or make Deutsch to explicitly update only one or the other.

There's a few things wrong here.   You should understand the difference between a Make variable (one declared in the global scope), and a bash variable (one defined within a target recipe).  One is global, and set at makefile parse time.   A bash variable is set on the recipe line as the recipe line is being run.  Once that recipe line is complete, the variable is no longer set (so a subsequent recipe line will not know about any variables set in the previous line...).
In your case you are setting FILE inside of a recipe line (plus you're setting it wrong -- bash doesn't allow spaces around = signs...).   Thus it will not be set until the recipe runs, and will not effect any references to it outside of that particular recipe line.
Also see here for a description of why not to use makefile conditionals inside of a recipe.
So basically, you want to set a Makefile variable, and use that as so:
# Declare make variables:                                                                                                                 
LANG               := DE
ifeq ($(LANG), DE)
FILE               := ./directory/resume_de
else ifeq ($(LANG), EN)
FILE               := ./directory/resume_en
else
$(error "LANG is not set, use DE/EN")
endif

all: ${FILE}.pdf move

${FILE}.pdf: ${FILE}.tex
        latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=${PDFLATEX} -f -use-make ${FILE}.tex  

Notice that because the set is in make context, you need to use $(error ...) instead of an echo/exit (which are bash commands).
As far as using a single command line, if you do:
make LANG=DE
Then the line LANG := DE will not have override the value set on the command line, and LANG will remain as EN.

Thanks a lot, meanwhile I manage to make it work somehow :| I realized myself as that space was causing the trouble. So removing the spacing 'FILE=FILE_NAME' and somehow keeping them inside the recipe worked for me. I run the script using make LANG=EN FILE=file_path However, surely I truly appreciate the knowledge shared here. I will use this to write a optimal makefile:) Thank you so much!

Keeping the assignments inside of the recipe would not work...   Again, it would set a bash variable, which Make itself would have no knowledge of.   If you run with FILE=file_path, then that is where FILE is being populated, and the assignment in the makefile would have no effect.   You should be able to run with just make LANG=EN with either my or @MadScientist's answer

Yeah, I modified it and now the assignments are without rules and its working just as you wrote make OR make LANG=EN :) Thank you so much :)

You didn't misunderstand conditionals.  You misunderstand rules and how they work.  If we remove the conditional (to see what make parses) we get this:
rule:
        FILE               = ./directory/resume_de

What is this?  It's rule that tells make, if you want to build the target named rule, then the recipe to do that is to start a shell and run the command FILE = ./directory/resume_de as a shell command.  That's what a rule is: a target, zero or more prerequisites, and a shell script to run a recipe.
But of course, that's not what you want.  You don't want to have to build a target named rule and you certainly don't want to have a shell try to parse that command (which, if nothing else, is an error in a shell script).
You don't want the rule stuff.  Just write:
# Variables Declaration                                                                                                                 
LANG               = DE
ifeq ($(LANG), DE)
  FILE             = ./directory/resume_de
else ifeq ($(LANG), EN)
  FILE             = ./directory/resume_en
else
  $(error "LANG is not set, use DE/EN")
endif

(note, no TAB chars at the beginning of these lines: you don't want to run them as shell scripts because you're trying to set make variable not shell variables.)
If I were going to write this makefile I'd do it like this:
# Variables Declaration                                                                                                                 
LANG = DE

FILE_DE = ./directory/resume_de
FILE_EN = ./directory/resume_en

FILE = $(FILE_$(LANG))

all: ${FILE}.pdf move

%.pdf: %.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=${PDFLATEX} -f -use-make $<

Or, if you're willing to use a lowercase language specifier and have your language files match them, you could just write this:
# Variables Declaration                                                                                                                 
LANG = de

FILE = ./directory/resume_$(LANG)

all: ${FILE}.pdf move

%.pdf: %.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=${PDFLATEX} -f -use-make $<


Just to note the move prerequisite is probably wrong here.  It will work ONLY IF you do not use parallel builds.  The move target (I'm assuming) depends on the pdf file having  already been created, but simply listing two files as prerequisites of the same file doesn't create a dependency relationship between them.

That's definitely something I was  totally missing. Thanks a lot :) :) It helps me a lot to write optimal makefile..and now I know why I had to run my makefile via 'make LANG=EN FILE=fille_path', however I remember when I was using FILE varialbe w/o rule, I still had to run it always make FILE=file_path. I will certainly do more testing given these iformations. Thanks again :) :)

I don't understand why you want to set FILE on the make command line; that will override the value already set in the makefile.

well, I copied the recipe that you suggested. It worked great and I could just do make OR make LANG=en. However, it works for above mentioned document,  more clearly for cover_letter: FILE = ./directory/coverletter_$(LANG).
However, when sometimes I need to make changes in curriculum_de/en I need to use make FILE=./directory/curriculum_$(LANG) OR make FILE=./directory/curriculum_$(LANG) LANG=en.
